# How to get the PID, process name, command line of the current terminal window session?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I was trying to find out, how do i get the pid, process name, command line of the current terminal(what is running in the background and got started with that terminal)?

Comment: is it ps -T? or is that wrong

Comment: "Current terminal window session" is not well-defined. In trivial cases your script's standard output will be connected to that TTY etc but there are a myriad ways in which a script could call another script etc and not have a terminal at all, and of course there is no guarantee that there is a window or window sesssion even if that's not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By running:

```
echo $$

15925
```

You will get the process ID of your current session. Using this process ID, you can then run:

```
ps -ef | grep 15925

foo     14870 15925  0 10:32 pts/6    00:00:00 sleep 120
foo     14871 15925  0 10:32 pts/6    00:00:00 ps -ef
foo     14872 15925  0 10:32 pts/6    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 15925
foo     15925 15919  0 Nov23 pts/6    00:00:08 -bash
```

The second column will show the parent process (15925) and the second the parent